# How to implement the Moto Body rounded gauge

Tags: android-widget, wear-os, gauge

I am looking for a library or code snippet that implements the rounded gauge to Android Wear, like the Moto Body. How to implement it?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a library called Fit-Chart [avaiable at Github](https://github.com/txusballesteros/fit-chart).